# web gis application with geotools?

Tags: web-service, geotools, web

I need to create a new gis application with OpenLayers and PostGIS.

I think that Geotools is a good choice for the Layer between these two.
I thought about embedding geotools in a web application

Now I need same samples to understand how geotools can be used together with OpenLayers.

Everything I found so far is good for developing a Java client application and of course for receiving and processing geo objects, but nothing that could help to build a web application.

Where should I continue to look?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) which will probably provide the solution you need out of the box and will provide plenty of code samples if you really need.

Comment: I cannot use GeoServer since I have to authorize some objects on row level and GeoServer is only able to provide authorization on layer level. :-(

Comment: GeoServer will remain your best source of example code using GeoTools for web services

Comment: ok, that requires that I have to understand the structure of geoserver and geotools at the same time. Since I'm lost in all the pages of geoserver and geotools, do You have an idea where exactly I can find an example of an implementation which provides WMS  or an other service for a web client - like the nich beginner tutorial with the java application that displays the wolrd shape ?